# Why two enum constants can be used in same line?

Tags: java, enums

I created one Enum class:

```
public enum Currency {

    PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);

    private int value;

    private Currency(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

};
```

I am trying to use it in a main() method:

```
System.out.println(Currency.NICKLE.DIME.PENNY.QUARTER);
System.out.println(Currency.PENNY.QUARTER);
```

There is no error being generated by this. It prints the constant which is at the last.

Could somebody please explain it?

Comment: `NICKLE` is an instance of `Currency`. You can reference static fields of a class via an instance.  Generally you shouldn't, because it is confusing. Some IDEs detect this and tell you not to do it.

Comment: You should get a compiler warning - "_static member being accessed by instance reference_".

Comment: @Boris I am getting that warning! Just noticed

Comment: @khelwood So all the instance of enum class are static, right?

Comment: So whilst "_error being generated by this_" is strictly speaking true - you have ignored a compiler warning. Unless you know what you are doing, compiler warnings should not be ignored.

Comment: "_the **instance** of enum class are **static**_" - the words "instance" and "static" are mutually exclusive, what are you asking?

Comment: Let me restructure my statement: From one instance of enum class you can access another instance of same enum class? Which I haven't seen in normal Java class.

Comment: @Nicky Yes enums can be compared to `static final` fields in a normal class

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to add on a bit more to what has been said in the comments above.

Enum values are somewhat special. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#Java) entry on Java enums:

> An enum type in Java is actually a special compiler-generated class rather than an arithmetic type, and enum values behave as global pre-generated instances of that class. Enum types can have instance methods and a constructor (the arguments of which can be specified separately for each enum value).

So, while they are only generated *once* at compile time, they are special instances of the given enum type. As such, it has access to other members of the class. Note that this also implies that you cannot instantiate an enum type yourself (i.e. using `new`).

> From one instance of enum class you can access another instance of same enum class? Which I haven't seen in normal Java class.

This is also possible in a normal class, though frowned upon as it offers no real benefits and might even cause problems and bugs (through `NullPointerException`s).

Consider the following two classes:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public final static int MODE = 1;
  private String message;

  public SomeClass(String message)
  {
    this.message = message;
  }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass("bla");
    System.out.println(myObject.MODE);
    System.out.println(OtherClass.MODE);
  }
}
```

This would simply print out:

```
1
1
```

However, imagine that you are performing some task where you iterating through a list of `SomeClass` objects where some of the entries are potentially `null` (perhaps because they were removed from the collection at some point, or because `null` entries were allowed at insertion time for whatever reason).

In that case, if you were to access the `static` member through an instance, you would get an NPE, whereas accessing it through the class itself would work as expected.

Note that the behaviour that is described in the question is specific to `enum` types themselves (i.e. `Currency.NICKLE.DIME...`). There is a way to *mimic* that behaviour, as follows:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public static SomeClass REF; // not final anymore since 'this' must be the first line in a constructor call
  public String message; // note this is public now

  public SomeClass(String message)
  {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public void setRef() {
    REF = this;
  }
}

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SomeClass myObject = new SomeClass("bla!");
    System.out.println(myObject.REF);
    System.out.println(SomeClass.REF);
    myObject.setRef();
    System.out.println(SomeClass.REF);
    System.out.println(SomeClass.REF.message);
  }
}
```

This would print out:

```
null
null
SomeClass@...  // Object.toString() call
bla!
```

But there is absolutely no benefit to gain from using such an awful technique and tons of drawbacks.